# What is the difference between Python's ElementTree.XML() and ElementTree.fromstring?

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

Pretty straightforward question. Given the string

```
s = "<blah x='true'><img src='a.jpg' /><a><b></b></a></blah>"
```

both of the following python commands produce the same output:

```
>>> E.tostring(E.fromstring(s))
'<blah x="true"><img src="a.jpg" /><a><b /></a></blah>'
>>> E.tostring(E.XML(s))
'<blah x="true"><img src="a.jpg" /><a><b /></a></blah>'
```

So why have two commands at all? I notice that in the Python 2.7 docs for ElementTree, the reference for `fromstring()` contains the phrase, " Same as XML()." So if it's the same, why include it?

The only difference I notice is that recent versions of Python have added the optional `parser` argument to `XML()` but not to `fromstring()`. Why? Is there actually a subtle difference in how the commands work or some reason why there are two commands that are apparently the same? Is it just for convenience's sake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fromstring` is exactly same as `XML`. In fact, it is defined like this:

```
##
# Parses an XML document from a string constant.  Same as {@link #XML}.
#
# @def fromstring(text)
# @param source A string containing XML data.
# @return An Element instance.
# @defreturn Element

fromstring = XML
```

You can check the source [here](http://svn.effbot.org/public/tags/elementtree-1.3a3-20070912/elementtree/ElementTree.py). I think it is there as a complement to the `tostring` function.

Comment: Huh. I suppose the idea of a complimentary function makes sense. Any idea why the function signatures are different, with `fromstring` missing the optional `parser` arg? It looks like it should support it, if it's literally defined as an alias for `XML`.

Comment: @KenB it wouldn't be a complementary function if it took extra parameters. For when you need to pass the extra parameters, you can call the `XML` function directly.

Comment: @KenB Since `fromstring` is defined as a direct alias for `XML`, you can pass the extra parameter to it too. It is just not mentioned in the doc, probably to discourage using it that way.